# Why does the ASP.NET text shorthand in HTML header not render?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So.. this is the upper part of my ASPX file in an MVC project:

```
<head runat="server">
   <link href="<%= ViewData[SomeNamespace.StyleSheetKey];" %> rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<div foo="<%= (string) ViewData[SomeNamespace.StyleSheetKey] %>">bar</div>
```

Now the div tag renders the stylesheet name properly, but the one in the link-tag is rendered as it is written, without being interpreted. In addition a path prefix is added.

So the ASP.NET engine seems to want to hassle with the text in the href-argument in the link tag, "helping" me to prefix my .css file with the correct relative path.

1. Why? Don't you think I'm able to write the correct path myself?
2. How will I now be able to set the name of the style sheet programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to start

```
<%= ViewData[SomeNamespace.StyleSheetKey];" %>
```

needs to be

```
<%= ViewData[SomeNamespace.StyleSheetKey]; %>"
```

You got the quotes in the wrong place.

Comment: *sigh* My bad, I farked up when writing this question, but not in my test code - the problem is still as I described. I posted a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756641/how-to-set-stylesheet-programmatically-in-an-asp-net-mvc-2-project