# How to set stylesheet programmatically in an ASP.NET MVC 2 project?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

So.. this is the upper part of my site.master ASPX file in an MVC2 project:

```
<head runat="server">
   <link href="<%= ViewData[SomeNamespace.StyleSheetKey]; %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<div foo="<%= (string) ViewData[SomeNamespace.StyleSheetKey] %>">bar</div>
```

Now the div tag renders the stylesheet name properly, but the one in the link-tag is rendered as it is written, without being interpreted. In addition a path prefix is added.

So the ASP.NET engine seems to want to hassle with the text in the href- argument in the link tag, "helping" me to prefix my .css file with the correct relative path.

How will I now be able to set the name of the style sheet programmatically?

Comment: I now it's a long shot, but try removing the runat="server" tag from the <head>

Comment: You sir, are the winner :-) Post it as an answer, not a comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Try removing the runat="server" tag from the `<head>` tag

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
 <link href="<%= "" + ViewData[SomeNamespace.StyleSheetKey] %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but this doesn't

```
  <link href="<%= (string)ViewData[SomeNamespace.StyleSheetKey] %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Or as The_Butcher says, remove the `runat="server"` from the header